# Algorithm to detect entity (aircraft, ship, etc) intrusion into geographic area

Tags: algorithm, area, feature-extraction, geofencing

I have been tasked with coming up with an algorithm to determine whether or not an entity (aircraft, ship, etc) is inside or outside of a geographic area defined as a set of geodetic (lat/long) vertices.  I receive a live stream of periodic position updates for each entity and must make the inside-outside determination upon each received update.

No graphics or imagery is involved on my end, simply data processing. I have a set of vertices that defines an area and a set of points for which I need to determine whether each is inside or outside the area.

What I do with each entity update is determined by the outcome of the inside/outside determination.  I'm a novice in this area so am not even sure where to begin looking.

The development environment is a complicating factor. We're developing in Visual Studio C++ 2003 (yes 2003!) on a Windows XP box. We'll be modernizing, but that is opening a whole can of worms we can't open right now. We need to add the functionality first. I know that will rule out some solutions. I might even have to get creative and perhaps have a dedicated machine (running a more modern OS and using Visual Studio 2013) to offload the inside/outside determination for each entity position update.

I can't say too much about the project domain (military), but you can imagine there would be many military applications where users define geographic areas (in this case irregular polygons) and want to know which platform entities (vehicles of various types) are inside or outside of each area. This is undoubtedly a common problem solved by many before me.

So my question is what algorithms are available to solve this problem?  What off-the-shelf third party tools?

Comment: What you are describing is known as geofencing - there should many hits when you google that.

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking. What kind of input will you have about this entity?

Comment: I think you are talkimg about geofencing but @Aaron thinks it is feature extraction/detection.  Either seems possible from reading your question.  Can you **edit** to clarify, please?

Comment: If you're unfamiliar with the technology, you shouldn't be eager to reinvent the bugs associated with the first three or four revisions of this particular wheel.  There are a number of potential rigorously tested implementations available, but steering you to the most appropriate one will require a great deal more information about the environment in which you're operating, and which tools might be already available.

Comment: Point-in-polygon might also be a useful search term.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.  The application is to define irregular areas (via lat/long vertices) and to be able to tell when an entity (aircraft, vehicle, vessel) enters and leaves that area. An example might be a restricted airspace.

Comment: Re:  "If you're unfamiliar with the technology, you shouldn't be eager to reinvent the bugs associated with the first three or four revisions of this particular wheel."  That's probably good advice, no matter how interesting opening that can of worms might be.  In the end, the functionality is what's important.  Boss wouldn't be keen on paying for my learning curve if unnecessary.  I've updated the original question with further detail.

Comment: "Geofencing" and "Point-in-polygon" were very useful search terms.  Regarding input, I get a continuous live stream of position updates (lat/long/altitude) for entities and what I do with that information depends on whether they are inside or outside of the polygon defined as a set of lat/long vertices.

Comment: I getting some ideas from various sources (Googling the terms suggested) that may facilitate an efficient algorithm, though I haven't fleshed out all the details. If an aircraft is outside, a line originating from it (direction unimportant) will cross the polygon boundary zero or an even number of times.  If inside, an odd number of times. The bounding box for the entire area can be tiled, with each tile in the tile matrix determined to be "in" or "out" by counting the intersections with the polygon boundary segments of a line originating from its center. continued...

Comment: Then determining whether a particular aircraft/vehicle position is in or out becomes a lookup in the tile matrix, which might be sped up by hash function to determine row and column. Intensive processing done once at area object construction time. A lot of untested ideas right now. Need to prototype. Would trade for an off the shelf solution if I can find one. There is error where tiles overlap boundaries, but can be kept acceptable through choice of tile size.

Comment: A quick pre-check for inclusion would be to check if position is "in" or "out" of the polygon bounding box. This is a very simple and inexpensive determination. If "out", no further processing (tile matrix lookup) is necessary.  This pre-check might save some cycles as well, but may be unnecessary if lookup efficient enough.

Comment: One of the things that currently stumps me is how to determine if great circle segment originating at tile center and some other (far away, beyond max area size) point intersects great circle segment between each pair of adjacent points in polygon.  Tile center is inside if the great circle segment originating at its center intersects polygon boundaries an odd number of times.

Comment: Thank you for the additional details (+1). Could you indicate your speed and accuracy requirements? They will steer the answers in appropriate directions. *By far* the fastest and simplest methods are image-based, because they take almost no time at all and are easy to program and test, but for greater accuracy you have to go to more sophisticated algorithms utilizing data structures like quadtrees.

Comment: No, I cannot talk about speed or accuracy requirements as it might say something about the capabilities of the system I am working on.  Unfortunately image-based will not work for me, as I get binary position data only and have binary coordinates to define the areas.  I think I have an idea of what I could do (see my previous comments above), but this would be a significant effort to develop from scratch.  I think most of the processing expense would be up front tiling the area, however.  It is possible the lookup (whether a position is in or out of the area) would be very fast.

Answer (score 1):

This is commonly referred to as feature detection.  There are many software packages that have libraries for feature detection/extraction.  To name a few:

Python ([Scikit-image](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/)):

- [Template Matching](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_template.html)
- [Blob Detection](http://scikit-image.org/docs/dev/auto_examples/plot_blob.html#example-plot-blob-py)

Matlab:

- [Feature Detection and Extraction](http://www.mathworks.com/help/vision/feature-detection-extraction-and-matching.html?refresh=true)